# Display records from two tables side by side matching only some of the fields

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, `table A`:

```
Customer_ID  Product  Date Of Sale  Pay Meth 1  Pay Meth 2  QTY
-----------  -------  ------------  ----------  ----------  ---
        123  AB       1/1/2012             111         222    1
        123  AB       1/1/2012             111         222    1
        456  AC       2/1/2012             333         444    1
```

and `table B`:

```
Customer_ID  Product  Date Of Sale  Pay Meth 1  Pay Meth 2  QTY
-----------  -------  ------------  ----------  ----------  ---
        123  AB       1/1/2012             111         222    2
        456  AB       1/1/2012             124         111    1
```

I want to match the data up so that the record for customer `123` in `table A` is grouped as :

```
Customer_ID  Product  Date Of Sale  Pay Meth 1  Pay Meth 2  QTY
-----------  -------  ------------  ----------  ----------  ---
        123  AB       1/1/2012             111         222    2
```

and to the right of it appears the following record from `table B`:

```
Customer_ID  Product  Date Of Sale  Pay Meth 1  Pay Meth 2  QTY
-----------  -------  ------------  ----------  ----------  ---
        123  AB       1/1/2012             111         222    2
```

Also (there is always an also) we want to show the third record in `table A` and to the right of that record the second record in `table B` (customer `456`) because they Have the same `Customer_ID`, `Product` and `Date of Sale`

So it should look something like

```
Customer_ID  Product  Date Of Sale  Pay Meth 1  Pay Meth 2  QTY  Customer_ID  Product  Date Of Sale  Pay Meth 1  Pay Meth 2  QTY
-----------  -------  ------------  ----------  ----------  ---  -----------  -------  ------------  ----------  ----------  ---
        123  AB       1/1/2012             111         222    1          123  AB       1/1/2012             111         222    1
        456  AC       2/1/2012             333         444    1          456  AB       1/1/2012             124         111    1
```

Comment: As @AlexKalicki points out, the product and date for `456` don't match between the tables; is that just a mistake writing this up? Also, do you really want all the matching columns to be repeated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a subquery on each table to get the  sum qty for each customer and then join the results on by the customer id 
e.g

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM (
    Select customer_id, product, dateofsale, PayMeth1, PayMeth2, SUM(Qty) as Qty
    from TableA
    Group by customer_id, product, dateofsale, PayMeth1, PayMeth2
) a
JOIN (
    Select customer_id, product, dateofsale, PayMeth1, PayMeth2, SUM(Qty) as Qty
    from TableB
    Group by customer_id, product, dateofsale, PayMeth1, PayMeth2
) b 
ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the SQL JOIN command:
http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqljoin.php

You'd want to join the two tables only for rows where the column(s) you want to match do so.  So if you're trying to match records from the two tables based on customer_id then your SQL code would look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN B
ON A.Customer_ID = B.Customer_ID
```

Not sure what you mean when you say those 2 records have the same ID, Product, and Date of Sale though - they seem to only have an ID (456) in common.

Comment: That doesn't deal with the grouping of `QTY` from `table A`.

Comment: Good point, I didn't realize that's what the OP wanted to do before the edit.  I can't think of a good way of doing it without deleting one entry from the table and updating the other with the correct quantity though.

Comment: I was struggling to see what was going on <grin>. I'd change the `from A` to `from (select id, ... sum(qty) from A group by id, ...) A`, so you're joining to a subquery that does the aggregation. Don't have time to write up a worked example just now though.

Comment: Thanks fro responding... you are correct i typoed the data for the 2nd example result. The issue i am having is that i want to pull back 6 ciolumns but only match on three... when i do it in a way similar to yours and i add more columns i get more records. so instead of showing the records that match it seems to be bulding iterations