# How to combine two query results into one and I have different column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two queries I want to combine into a single output, I can't use a Union operator because they have different numbers of columns.

```
**First query result**

A1     A2

10     15

**Second query Result**

B1   B2

5      10

**The final result would be**

A1    A2     B1     B2

10    15     5       10
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do they have the same number of rows in all cases?

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783343/display-records-from-two-tables-side-by-side-matching-only-some-of-the-fields

Comment: Yes The number of rows are same

Answer (score 7):

If you only have one row from each query, it's just a `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (query1)   AS q1
CROSS JOIN
  (query2)   AS q2
```

If you have more than one row from each query, you need an `INNER JOIN` or maybe a `FULL OUTER JOIN` and some relationship between the two sets of data, so that you can tell the SQL engine which row joins to which row...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (query1)   AS q1
FULL OUTER JOIN
  (query2)   AS q2
      ON  q2.id2 = q1.id1   -- Or some other predicate
```

Note:

- `UNION` appends data vertically
- `JOIN` appends data horizantally

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM q1
LEFT JOIN q2 ON 1 = 1
```