# SQL How to join two query's with different columns and joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 2 queries both use joins, select various columns from multiple tables which produce the below result sets:

```
companyID   workType    contractnumber  employeenumber  Value2
1           1C          9999999         111111          2547.21
1           1C          9999999         222222          863.67
1           1C          9999999         333333          2962.15
1           1C          9999999         444444          1971.61
1           1C          9999999         555555          152.41
1           1C          9999999         666666          155.90
1           1C          9999999         777777          657.20


companyID   normalWorkType  employeeNumber  value1
1           1C              11111           1016.08
1           1C              22222           3118.05
1           1C              33333           2628.81
1           61              44444           2547.21
```

I'm looking to join these to produce the below result.. can anyone explain what the correct syntax would be?

```
companyID   normalWorkType  contractnumber  employeeNumber  value1  Value2
1           1C              9999999         11111           1016.08 2547.21
1           1C              9999999         22222           3118.05 863.67
1           1C              9999999         33333           2628.81 2962.15
1           61              9999999         44444           2547.21 1971.61
1           1C              9999999         55555           0       152.41
1           1C              9999999         66666           0       155.90
1           1C              9999999         77777           0       657.20
```

Grouping above is on companyID & employeeNumber

Comment: join on a.companyid = b.companyid and a.worktype = b.normalworktype and a.employeenumber = b.employeenumber?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try LEFT OUTER JOIN:**

```
SELECT t1.companyID,
       t2.normalWorkType,
       t1.contractnumber,
       t1.employeeNumber,
       coalesce(t2.value1,0) as t2.value1,
       t1.value2
FROM DatabaseName.t1 AS t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     DatabaseName.t2 AS t2 ON t1.employeenumber = t2.employeenumber  
       AND t1.companyID = t2.companyID
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming here that the contract numbers in the proposed result set are actually the contract numbers from your first query, and that the difference is just a typo. If that's true, this will get you what you want.

```
SELECT
  q1.companyID   
  COALESCE(q2.normalWorkType,q1.workType) AS normalWorkType
  q1.contractnumber  
  q1.employeeNumber  
  COALESCE(q2.value1  ,0) as value1
  q1.Value2
FROM
  (
    <Your first query>
  ) as q1
LEFT JOIN
  (
    <Your second query>
  ) as q2
    ON
      q1.companyID = q2.companyID
      AND
      q1.employeeNumber = q2.employeeNumber;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Eric, fortunately I came to a solution from another answer before seeing this, however you did spot the typo and your answer has relevance. Up-voted for these reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Query

```
select Table1.companyId,Table2.normalworktype,Table1.contractnumber,
Table1.employeenumber,Table2.value1,Table1.value2 
from Table1 
inner join Table2 on Table1.companyid = Table2.companyid 
      and Table1.employeeNumber=Table2.employeeNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses everyone,

After trying Husam Ebish's suggestion It wasn't quite what I needed but lead me to this thread. (up-voted your answer)

[How to combine two query results into one and I have different column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467940/how-to-combine-two-query-results-into-one-and-i-have-different-column-name)

What I really found useful was this bit of information highlighted below from the linked thread. After trying the different "left" joins suggested the comment's highlighted lead me to try "full outer join" which has given me the correct result-set.

> If you only have one row from each query, it's just a CROSS JOIN

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (query1)   AS q1
CROSS JOIN
  (query2)   AS q2
```

> If you have more than one row from each query, you need an INNER JOIN
>   or maybe a FULL OUTER JOIN and some relationship between the two sets
>   of data

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (query1)   AS q1
FULL OUTER JOIN
  (query2)   AS q2
      ON  q2.id2 = q1.id1
```

Note:

- `UNION` appends data vertically
- `JOIN` appends data horizontally

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (select top 1  VL1,VL2,VL3 from current_voltage AS q1
where deviceimei ='233'
order by devicetimestamp)   AS q1
CROSS JOIN
  (select top 1  OTI,WTI,ATI from overview  AS q2
where deviceimei ='233'
order by devicetimestamp  )   AS q2
```

Comment: If your attempting to answer the OP's question you should really use there example data in your reply, not something completely different as it may confuse them e.g they don't have a table called `current_voltage`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25773617)

Answer (score -2):

You can put your search result to 2 temp table and then join this 2 temp table or use alliance for your each select and then join them.
like :

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM (
  SELECT 
     companyID
    ,workType
    ,contractnumber
    ,employeenumber
    ,Value2
  FROM table1
  ) t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
     companyID
    ,normalWorkType
    ,contractnumber
    ,employeeNumber
    ,value1
    ,Value2
  FROM table2
  ) t2 
    ON t1.companyID = t2.companyid
```

or put your result 2 different temp table and then join them

```
SELECT 
   companyID
  ,workType
  ,contractnumber
  ,employeenumber
  ,Value2
INTO #tt1
FROM table1

SELECT 
   companyID
  ,normalWorkType
  ,contractnumber
  ,employeeNumber
  ,value1
  ,Value2
INTO #tt2
FROM table2

SELECT *
FROM #tt1 t1
INNER JOIN #tt2 t2 ON t1.companyid = t2.companyID
```

Comment: An inner join on the two interim result sets will be limited to the rows with matches in both sets. The OP here is asking for an outer join. Also, building temp tables here just adds unnecessary overhead to the operation. It was the inner join, though, which is in both of your answers, that caused me to vote your answer down. It will return incorrect results.